# how to install squid 3.3 on windows

Tags: windows, cygwin

I want to run squid 3.3 on windows.

The site http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/ seems out of date (latest files are 2010).

How can I install squid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me on windows 7. First I install cygwin, then I install squid.
Copy cygwin [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) to local windows folder, them from *CMD.exe* prompt:

```
set CYG_SITE=http://sourceware.mirrors.tds.net/pub/sourceware.org/cygwin/
setup -R c:\dev\cygwin\root -q -C Base -n -d -O -s %CYG_SITE%
setup -q -P subversion
```

The rest of the instructions are done from the cygwin bash shell
(*c:\dev\cygwin\root\cygwin.bat* in my case). Install apt-cyg:

```sh
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
apt-cyg install squid # Install squid
/usr/sbin/squid -z    # Initialise squid
/usr/sbin/squid       # Start squid
```

Now open IE to ensure squid is running - point it to http://localhost:3128 -
you should see the following error:

> [image: squid_error]

Now you need to configure squid. The configuration files are found in cygwin in
the folder */etc/squid*.

Comment: +1 for the `-z` flag

Comment: This worked for me. Note the path to cygwin setup has changed. It is now http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe. I have a question: how to install it as a Windows service ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to install and run Squid as described in previous answer.

Then create Windows service for Squid using this command:

```
c:/cygwin/bin/cygrunsrv.exe -I "squid" -d "CYGWIN Squid" -p /usr/sbin/squid -a "-N" -u .\cyg_server -y tcpip --type auto
```

Comment: I had to replace cyg_server with Administrator to install service, and then in services.msc change the login type to "Local System Account" and then it works.

Comment: You may as well skip the parameter `-u .\cyg_server`

Answer (score 1):

SHC answer worked for me except apt-cyg install instructions pointed at older version which was bombing md5sum check for me.  See https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg for current version.

install apt-cyg:

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /usr/bin
```